# Eclipse / ADB not detecting Droid Razr M

Tags: android, eclipse, adb

ADB is no longer recognizing my Droid Razr M (Android 4.4.2).

I'm using the Eclipse ADT bundle (23.0.0.1245622) on Windows 7 64-bit.

I can verify that adb works and detects other phones.

This phone has been working with adb for a while now, but just doesn't work anymore.

So far I've tried the following:

1. Unplug the phone's USB cable and reconnect to computer
2. Used a different USB cable
3. Restart Eclipse
4. Changed the USB connection to Camera (PTP)
5. Changed it back to Media device (MTP)
6. Restart phone
7. Reboot computer (this has actually worked in the past)
8. Made sure Developer Options and USB debugging are enabled
9. Restart adb server with `adb kill-server` / `adb start-server`
   (`adb devices` always returns an empty list)
10. Installed the Universal ADB Driver
11. Factory reset phone

Does anyone have any experience with troubleshooting a Razr M with adb, or have any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working.  Even though I had updated my device drivers with Motorola Device Manager, apparently Windows didn't like the driver.  To fix it you have to manually tell the Android USB driver about your specific device's hardware ids, then update the driver in Windows Device Manager.

First go to Windows Device Manager and under Android Device you should see an entry for something like Android or ADB device.  Right-click on it, select Properties, Details, and in the drop-down menu select Hardware Ids.

They'll look something like this:

> USB\Vid_22b8&Pid_2e51&Rev_0228&Mi_02
>   USB\Vid_22b8&Pid_2e51&Mi_02
>   USB\Vid_22b8&Pid_2e51&Class_ff&SubClass_42

Copy those and then navigate to:

C:\Program Files\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140624\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver

You'll find a file called `android_winusb.inf` there.

Open it up and use your Hardware Ids to add an entry like this under `[Google.NTx86]`:

> ;Droid Razr M
>   %CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_22B8&PID_2E51&MI_02
>   %CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_22B8&PID_2e51&REV_0228&MI_02
>   %CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_22B8&PID_2E51&CLASS_FF&SUBCLASS_42

Then add the same entry under `[Google.NTamd64]`.

Finally, go back to Device Manager and right-click on your Android / ADB device, Properties, Driver, Update Driver and point to the directory where your `android_winusb.inf` is.  It'll give you a warning about not being able to verify the driver.  Just ignore it and install it anyway.

After doing that, I unplugged my device and plugged it in, and it was working fine again over adb.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the screen is unlocked.  I seem to remember running into a similar problem where the screen was locked and it was then locking out USB connections too.

Comment: I just turned off screen lock and it didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Is the connection otherwise acting normal?  For example, does MotoCast connect to the phone?

Comment: Yes, it was otherwise acting normal.  I did end up figuring it out though.  I just posted it below.